# About semipositive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite matrices
$A \ge B\ge 0$

Is the statement $A^2\geq B^2$ true or false? Why?

$\geq$ means nonnegative pointwise

Comment: What do you mean by non-negative pointwise?

Comment: What is *semipositive*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(A)_{ij}\geq (B)_{ij}\geq 0$ (for $i,j=1,\ldots,n$), then
$$
(A^2)_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^n(A)_{ik}(A)_{kj}\geq \sum_{k=1}^n(B)_{ik}(B)_{kj}=(B^2)_{ij}.
$$

Comment: I suppose $A \geq B$ means $A_{ij}\geq B_{ij}$ for all entries? Otherwise you need additional assumptions to ensure that the product of two positive matrices is positive.

Comment: @user161825 Yes, this is what I understood from the comments. The product of two nonnegative matrices is clearly nonnegative (each entry is a sum of products of nonnegative numbers).

Comment: Note that $(A+B)(A-B) = A^2 - B^2 - AB + BA$

Comment: @martini Oops! Indeed.

Comment: seems like it doesn't have something to do with the positive semi definite.@user161825

Answer (score 2):

Let $$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
Then 
$$ A^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 5 & 3\\ 3 & 2\end{pmatrix}, \quad B^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 2 & 2\end{pmatrix} $$
We have
$$ A - B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad 
 A^2- B^2 = \begin{pmatrix}  3 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} $$
We have $A-B \ge 0$, but $\det(A^2 - B^2) = -1 < 0$, that is $A^2-B^2 \not\ge 0$.

Comment: $\geq$ means nonnegative pointwise not positive definite

Comment: Then you should write that in your question. In the context of positive matrices, $A \ge B$ usually denotes "$A-B$ is positive semidefinite".

Comment: my apologize...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose $A\ge B$ means $A-B$ is positive semidefinite. Then I'm pretty sure that $A^2\ge B^2$ is a wrong statement, whose counterexample can be easily found in the case $2\times 2$ matrix (see the other answer).

There is nevertheless an interesting true statement, which is $A^{-1}\leq B^{-1}$ (if they both exist)

Hope I'm not wrong :)

Comment: how to get a-b is positive semidefinite?

Comment: It depends on how you define the relationship $A \ge B$. There is no "formal" definition for that. Here I assume you have defined $A\ge B$ as $A-B$ is positive semidefinite.

If your definition is different, you should notice it.